# Different logging level between SFL4J and JDK logging

Tags: logging, slf4j, java.util.logging

I am using JDK logging as a logging framework and SLF4J as simple facade.
I have some queries when I log different level logs.

**SLF4J has following log levels**

```
trace (the least serious)<br>
debug<br>
info<br>
warn<br>
error<br>
fatal (the most serious)<br>
```

**JDK logging has following log levels**

```
SEVERE (highest value)<br>
WARNING<br>
INFO<br>
CONFIG<br>
FINE<br>
FINER<br>
FINEST (lowest value)<br>
```

If I want to set the log level to DEBUG then that level is not available in JDK logging.
Can anybody please explain how can we get the DEBUG level logging in this situation. Do we need to do any additional configuration for this situation?

**Updated**

this is my property file configuration

```
handlers = com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler

com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler.pattern=c:/logs/debug_log.log
com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler.level=FINE
com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler.append=true
```

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278438/slf4j-logging-with-jdk-how-to-enable-debug

Comment: I have changed the log level to FINE which mentiooned in the above link but still I am not getting the DEBUG level logging.

Comment: The solution which you gave didnt help me to resolve my issue. I have updated my post with the my property file configuration.

Comment: My solution to any JDK logging problem is to use log4j.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the help of bellow post.

[slf4j logging with jdk – how to enable debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278438/slf4j-logging-with-jdk-how-to-enable-debug)

For DEBUG level logging in SLF4J we have to map FINE level in java.util.logging.

And we have to set the default logging level as FINE or lower level of FINE.
This can be achieved by putting the bellow line in logging configuration file.

.level= FINE

Answer (score 0):

One further problem you have is that although you've defined a handler, you haven't assigned it to any loggers.

To assign it to the root logger, use

```
.handlers=com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler
```

To assign it to a logger in your application, define the logger

```
com.company.application.package.level=FINE
```

And assign your handler to it:    `com.company.application.package.handlers=com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler`

Also, is com.amc.logging.handlers.DebugLogHandler a class that you defined yourself? Is it in your classpath? Because otherwise I don't think java.util.logging (JUL) will recognize it.

Try one of the handlers that comes with JUL:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

And configure them with the level, log location and format that you want.

Here's an example logging.properties file: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)

It uses handlers from apache's juli implementation, but just substitute with classes from JUL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html