# The google cloud dataflow eclipse plugin is not able to show the TRACE logs or any logs below error when configured

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am unable to see the logs when I configure the google cloud dataflow eclipse plugin as documented which is setting workerLogLevelOverrides to  {\"com.mycompany.testdataflow.StarterPipeline\":\"TRACE\"}

The strange bit is doing this configuration for ERROR level seems to show the logs but anything lower doesnt.

Could anyone have come across this?

Here is the code segment I am using to try and output the logs

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarterPipeline.class);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

    for (String string : args) {
        // System.out.println("########## "+string);
        LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline ##### Parameter is #### " + string);

        LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline ##### Parameter is #### ");
    }

    LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline");
    p.apply(Create.of("Hello", "World")).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline");
            c.output(c.element().toUpperCase());
        }
    })).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline");
            LOG.info(c.element());
        }
    }));
```

This is from the dataflow example except for the logging that I added to see if I am able to see any logs.

Comment: What PipelineRunner are you using? Where are you looking for the logs? Which log in specific are you looking for? Have you looked at the [DebuggingWordCount example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example#debugging-wordcount-example) which talks about logging?

Comment: @BenChambers Thanks for your quick response. I am using the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner , I am looking for the logs on the console (eclipse console) for the logs like LOG.trace("Doing the trace for pipeline ##### Parameter is #### ");  which is a log line that I just added to see that something is being written on the console. But even when I look in the google cloud console under logs I am not able to see the logs I am looking for, infact in the log levels there is no TRACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a pipeline using `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` or `DataflowPipelineRunner` there are two parts to execution. First, your main method is run locally on your machine to produce the pipeline. When you call `p.run()` the pipeline is shipped to the Dataflow service where it runs on (possibly many) virtual machines.

The log statements that are directly in the `main` method (such as "Doing the trace for pipeline ...") happen on your machine, and would show up in the Eclipse console. The log statements within the `DoFn`s happen on the virtual machines, and only show up in Cloud Logging, as described in [DebuggingWordCount example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example#using-cloud-logging).

Specifying `workerLogLevelOverrides` affects the log level of the worker virtual machines. So, changing that value will affect what gets logged by the `DoFn`s to Cloud Logging.

To adjust the log level of code running on your machine (so the `main` method) you need to adjust the SLF4J or java.util.logging log levels that the main program is run with. For example, [these instructions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278438/slf4j-logging-with-jdk-how-to-enable-debug) suggest using a logging config file.

Comment: This is it, I was looking at the wrong place, I can actually see the logs in google cloud logs. One issue though is that there is no trace in the log levels in the filter section, I saw the trace logs showing up as DEBUG severity looks like that is google's intention but it works for now. Thanks.